# It shows TypeError after run python scraping code(o'reilly example code)

Tags: python-3.x

I follow the example code of "O'Reilly Web Scraping with Python: Collecting More Data from the Modern Web" and find it shows error.

The versions are:
python3.7.3, BeautifulSoup4

The code is as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

import random

import datetime

import codecs


import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

def getLinks(articleUrl):

    html = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org{}',format(articleUrl))

    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    return bs.find('div', {'id':'bodyContent'}).find_all('a',

        href=re.compile('^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$'))

links = getLinks('/wiki/Kevin_Bacon')

links.encoding = 'utf8'

while len(links) > 0:

    newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs['href']

    print(newArticle)

    links = getLinks(newArticle)
```

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file 
>   object. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You don't appear to be issuing a POST request. What line of source corresponds to the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this rather old question, I see the problem is a typo (and I VTCed as such):

```
html = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org{}',format(articleUrl))
                                          ^
```

That comma `,` should be a dot `.`, otherwise [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) we are passing a second parameter `data`:

> *data* must be an object specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use *data*. The supported object types include bytes, file-like objects, and iterables of bytes-like objects.

Note the last sentence; the function expects an iterable of bytes, but `format()` returns a string, thus the error:

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.